# JMeter listeners which measure upstream bandwidth

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Are there any JMeter plugins which measure the upstream bandwidth of JMeter i.e. the sum of all the traffic generated by JMeter's requests? I know there is the summary report listener, which has a Throughput field, but this isn't really what I want, Ideally something which has the same metrics as something like [FreeMeter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemeter/).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Bytes Throughput Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/BytesThroughput/) is the plugin I wanted in the end from Jmeter-Plugins.org